# Why should I get the weapon durability upgrade?

Tags: heroville

In the Upgrades list, one of the options is to upgrade weapon durability.  Why would I want to do this?  Shouldn't I want weapons to break often so heroes need to buy more?

Answer (score 1):

Heroes that survive longer(which they can really only do with better weapons) come back with more loot resources for you. So although you may get less gold from them buying new weapons, you gain more resources.

When you go into longer and higher level dungeons, your heroes *can't* complete them without more durable weapons and defenses. You won't get any reward if they fail.

Comment: Sounds like this is a late-game upgrade that should be avoided as long as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The weapon durability is important for heroes who are in long dungeons to avoid reaching the situation where they only have a fist to beat on a strong monster.

It is currently a get only if absolutely necessary upgrade due to the fact it does come with a downside of losing the chance for your hero to earn the gold for buying a new upgrade.

In future updates, I know this feature will be changes to make more sense and be more worthwhile purchasing.